# Flash AS2 detecting dynamically attached components are initialised

Tags: flash, components, initialization, actionscript-2, addeventlistener

OK, driving myself mad trying to remember AS2 here, hoping for someone with better memory to lend a hand...

Basically, my problem is using composition and 'waiting' for components - eg. a Button component - to be ready to attach a click handler..for various reasons I can't do anything about the whole setup so here's the situation...

I have a movieclip in the library, no class, just a linkage ID ("AttachMe"). That clip has an AS2 Button component inside it ('btn').

I have a class that gets a reference to a timeline, then attaches the mc from the library, then adds an event listener to the button. Simple right?

```
var foo:Foo = new Foo(this);

class Foo {

    private var tl:MovieClip; // timeline
    private var mc:MovieClip; // the attached movieclip

    function Foo(t:MovieClip){
        tl = t;
        mc = tl.attachMovie("AttachMe", "mc", 10);
        var b:Button = mc.btn;
        b.addEventListener("click", Delegate.create(this, onClick));
    }
    private function onClick(e:Object):Void{
        trace("Hi!");
    }
}
```

This won't work, as b.addEventListener is undefined at the point I'm doing it...

So really, what is best practice here? i.e. this is a real pain, and I know it's the case of 'waiting' for the button component (in this case) to initialise before adding the event handler.

Could do an interval/timeout - hate the idea of that. Could do enterFrame on the mc, clear it on first call then add the handler..again, just seems wrong.
onLoad doesn't fire for the movieclip so can't add that (if I used inheritance and a custom sub class for the library movieclip I could use onLoad).

Each way seems to be a hack and the thought of doing many times is depressing! It must have been done to death over the years, but I really can't find anything directly mentioning the problem and accepted solutions...

Any thoughts appreciated!

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, third attempt, and I've marked the other answers for deletion.  After getting into the UIObject and Button classes I came up with this, which seems to work:

```
import mx.utils.Delegate;
import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.events.EventDispatcher;

class Foo {

    private var tl:MovieClip; // timeline
    private var mc:MovieClip; // the attached movieclip

    function Foo(t:MovieClip)
    {
        tl = t;
        mc = tl.attachMovie("AttachMe", "mc", 10);
        var b:Button = mc.btn;
        EventDispatcher.initialize(b);
        b.addEventListener("click", Delegate.create(this, onClick));
    }
    private function onClick(e:Object):Void
    {
        trace("Hi!");
    }
}
```

This important bit is `EventDispatcher.initialize(b);` which seems to force the methods into existence straight away.

Comment: Haha - still trying on it eh?
Given a button component already gets initialised by EventDispatcher in it's own code, Ive no idea if twice initialising does anything 'bad'. Think this way actually works as calling EventDispatcher.initialize on the button makes all that actionscript run, blocking the next line until it has - so once finished, addEventListener is available. i.e. the code is within the same block - whereas without it, b.addEventListener is called before the button - running independently of this code block, has fully initialised.
Still, it looks like it works - nice one!

Comment: I guess the only spanner in the works is that its not really a general solution - i.e. what if you had a whole load of components, not just 1 button? You would have to perform the same EventDispatcher.initialize on each and every one... whereas a method to delay for a frame tick would mean that wasn't necessary... see what I mean? Sure this shouldn't be this tricky!

Comment: It's things like this that got me into making my own components, and started me down the path of oop! That and the absurd file size increase that comes with them.  Looking back at some old projects, all my custom components do at some point call EventDispatcher.initialize().  I still prefer this to waiting for the frame to tick over because you can call it at the point of button creation, which for a whole lot of buttons isn't necessarily going to happen at the same time. It's still not great, but hey, that's why we've got AS3!

Comment: All good points :-) I guess I'll just get on with it, then go back to AS3! Thanks for taking the time to help out!